# The number of Hamiltonian circuits on a convex polytope embedded in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, convex-polytopes, hamiltonian-graphs

Recently I wondered whether there might be a natural topological complexity measure for convex polytopes embedded in $\mathbb{R}^N$. After some reflection it occurred to me that the number of distinct Hamiltonian cycles on a convex polytope may be a useful proxy measure. Now, let's suppose that the asymptotic formula for the maximum number of Hamiltonian cycles on an $n$-vertex convex polytope embedded in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
f_N(n) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

What I'm curious about is whether there exists a polynomial $P(n)$ such that:

\begin{equation}
\forall N \in \mathbb{N},\frac{f_{N+1}(n)}{f_{N}(n)} \leq P(n) \tag{2}
\end{equation}

For concreteness, in the case $(N=2,n=4)$ we have a square with 8 H-cycles and in the case $(N=3,n=4)$ we have a tetrahedron with 24 H-cycles.

**Note:** After doing several Google searches it's still unknown to me whether this problem has already been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $N\ge 4$ and arbitrary $n\ge N+1$ there is a [polytope with edge graph $K_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborly_polytope), hence $f_N(n)=n!$. So if $n\ge N+2$ then

$$\frac{f_{N+1}(n)}{f_N(n)} = 1.$$

Note also, that $f_N(n)$ is not well-defined for $n\le N$. So talking about *arbitrarily large* $N$ for fixed $n$ might be problematic.

Comment: I will try to demonstrate this but I'm also curious about the methods used in original references. Might there be a single paper that covers this result?

Comment: @AidanRocken What original reference do you mean? I am not specifically aware of using Hamiltonian cycles as complexity measure on polytopes, but that is not my field of expertise. If you want to read something about neighborly/cyclic polytopes, you might grab any standard reference on polytopes as e.g. Günter Ziegler's book.

Comment: M. Winter, thank you for this clarification.